# Select multiple fields with single group by in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I used Django query as :

```
 sports.PYST.objects.using( 'sports-data' ).all().values('season','player','team').annotate(max_count = Max('punt_long') ).query
```

It gives o/p like :

```
SELECT `PYST`.`SEASON`, `PYST`.`PLAYER`, `PYST`.`TEAM`, MAX(`PYST`.`PUNT_LONG`) AS `max_count` FROM `PYST` GROUP BY `PYST`.`SEASON`, `PYST`.`PLAYER`, `PYST`.`TEAM` ORDER BY NULL
```

What I expected :

```
select season,player,team,max(punt_long)as punt_long from PYST group by season
```

Can any one help on this or need any additional information ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without either:

1. raw sql
2. additional query to retrieve objects filtered by aggregation result (which is possible with little help from Q objects)

**Edit 1:**

Regarding solution no 2. This still may be not the best idea, but it's the quickest I could come up with:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Q
from operator import __or__ as OR

result_dict = Score.objects.values('season').annotate(Max('punt'))
q = [Q(season=row['season']) & Q(punt=row['punt__max']) for row in result_dict]
qs = Score.objects.filter(reduce(OR, q))
```

Check out this link for more details:
http://css.dzone.com/articles/best-way-or-list-django-orm-q

Comment: I don't want to use the raw sql. Can you please give example for the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late, but I hope it will work for someone today:

```
Model.objects.filter(name__in=["foo", "foo1"]).values('last_name')\
       .order_by('id')\
       .annotate(total=Count('id')).values('first_name')
```

Generate the following query:

```
SELECT "models_model"."first_name", COUNT("models_model"."id") AS "total" FROM "models_model" WHERE "models_model"."name" IN (...) GROUP BY "models_model"."last_name", "models_model"."author_id" ORDER BY "models_model"."id" ASC
```